# ReactJs-Cannot update a component (`TheLayout`) while rendering a different component (`Header`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Header`

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm facing an issue while I want to update context on child component,
I have a component for getting request from server,in child component I'm importing this component and send link and data to component and get the response!
my context is :

```
    import React from 'react'
    const UserContext = React.createContext();
    export default UserContext;
```

I'm going to send a request to server on Header Component if my State is empty

```
    const Header = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo || typeof userInfo === "undefined")
      requestHandler("/ankavita/panel/kullanici/data", "GET", null);
     console.log("use effect .......");
    }, []);

  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useContext(UserContext);
  const { isLoading, isError, data, requestHandler, msg } = MyRequest();
  if (isLoading) {
    console.log("is loading ...");
    return <p>is loaaading</p>;
  } else {
    console.log("loading is over ...");
    setUserInfo(data);
    return <p>Loading is over</p>;
  }
};
export default Header;
```

and I my layouts component

```
    const TheLayout = () => {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState();
  return (
    <>
      <UserContext.Provider value={[userInfo, setUserInfo]}>
        <Header />
        <Navigation />
        <Sidebar />
        <div id="main">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12">
              <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                <Route path="/panel/logout">
                    <Logout />
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/panel/login">
                    <Login />
                  </Route>
                   
                  <Route component={Page404} />
                  
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <RightSidebar />
        <Footer />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

I'm getting this error when I want to update Context
Cannot update a component (`TheLayout`) while rendering a different component (`Header`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Header`

Answer (score 0):

You should not perform side-effects during the render of a component.
In Header, you call setUserInfo which has a side-effect: updating TheLayout state.
You shoud wrap setUserInfo into a useEffect hook.

Comment: I did it and  errors fixed but now I didn't get any response I think My effect function must wait for response from my http request component right?

Comment: hard to say without seeing the whole code. you should make sure that MyRequest is triggered, and that it assigns its results somewhere useful, for exemple: in Header state. Happy coding!